# MYSQL CASE THEN statement with multiple values

Tags: mysql

I am trying go select multiple values with `CASE` statement. I noticed we cannot do

```
CASE 
    WHEN wall.type="bk" 
    THEN books.id1,books.id2, // and so on
END as column_1,
```

Is there a way to do `THEN` with multiple columns or do we need to simply write a bunch of `CASE THEN` statements? that seems messy

Comment: You could; but I don't recommend it; concatenate the multiple columns together and parse them out later`THEN books.id1|','|books.id2...`  just depends on overall what you're trying to do.  This would eliminate the problems of multiple values being returned and aliased as one. as it would be returning 1 value.

Comment: thanks for your time. could you explain how to do that?

Comment: CONCAT(books.ID1, ', ', books.id2, ', ' bookxId...)  will return 1, 2, 3 if booksid1... is 1,2,3 respectively.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, it is just a single value. Additionally, it is contradictory to use "multiple columns" and name those multiple columns as `column_1`, right? :)

You can use another column to store the other id with (a similar case) and use nulls to represent the `else` values, just like you're doing now.

Example:

```
CASE 
    WHEN wall.type="bk" 
    THEN books.id1
END as column_1,
CASE 
    WHEN wall.type="bk" 
    THEN books.id2
END as column_2
```

Check the [official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/case-statement.html) for more information.

Comment: But what if you want to update a user-defined value in the `THEN` clause?

Comment: @Lucas Hmm, not sure what you're talking about. Most likely that should be a different question

Comment: Another example of how MySQL violates the DRY principle every day of the week. I feel myself getting closer to making the audacious claim that learning MySQL before you learn any other language can help you develop bad habits.

Answer (score 5):

No. [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html) statement can only return a single value, so the only way to achieve what you want is duplicate the case ...

The database server should be optimized and perform only one time the check on the same condition ...

Answer (score 0):

And everything can be done, but it always depends on what you want to do. Below I'll show you a working example right after you have to take the data as an array and do what you want.

```
CREATE TABLE wall (`ident` int,`type` varchar(2), `order` int);
INSERT INTO wall (`ident`, `type`, `order`) VALUES
    (40,'bk', 1),
    (41,'bk', 5),
    (42,'rt', 2),
    (43,'bk', 3),
    (44,'rt', 1);

CREATE TABLE books (`ident` int,`id1` int, `time` varchar(8), `id2` int);
INSERT INTO books (`ident`, `id1`, `time`, `id2`) VALUES
    (40, 10, '18:07:00', 20),
    (43, 11, '05:00:00', 21),
    (44, 12, '21:01:00', 22),
    (41, 13, '10:00:00', 23),
    (42, 14, '23:10:00', 24);
#--------------------------
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN wall.type='bk' 
    THEN  CONCAT(books.id1,'-',books.id2) 
 END AS column_1

FROM wall JOIN books ON books.ident = wall.ident GROUP BY wall.ident ORDER BY wall.ident ASC;
```

Print:

```
 column_1
1   10-20
2   13-23
3   NULL
4   11-21
5   NULL
```

Solution in action via this link:
http://rextester.com/LHPI38373

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation [mysql_doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html); you can use the other syntax of case for what you wanted.

```
case
 WHEN FIND_IN_SET(edu, "1,1st,2,2nd,3,3rd,4,4th,5,5th,pri,primary,primery") THEN
  SET memEdu = "Primary";
 WHEN FIND_IN_SET(edu, "intermediate,inter,f.a,fa,fac,f.a.c,f.sc,fsc,1rd year,2rd year,3rd year") THEN
  SET memEdu = "Intermediate";
End case;
```