# SQL CASE statement syntax error when statement

Tags: mysql

```
select CASE 
    WHEN (S.Marks >= G.Min_Mark and S.Marks <= G.Max_Mark and G.Grade >= 8)
    THEN S.Name, G.grade, S.Marks
    WHEN (S.Marks >= G.Min_Mark and S.Marks <= G.Max_Mark and G.Grade < 8) 
    THEN 'NULL', G.grade, S.Marks
    END
FROM Students S, Grades G;
```

I am using mysql and I am getting syntax errors.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to return 3 separate fields from each case statement. They either need 3 separate case statements, or just pull out `G.grade`, and `S.Marks`, as they don't appear to need to be in the case at all. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10155928/4875631) answer for more information:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN (S.Marks >= G.Min_Mark and S.Marks <= G.Max_Mark and G.Grade >= 8)
        THEN S.Name
        WHEN (S.Marks >= G.Min_Mark and S.Marks <= G.Max_Mark and G.Grade < 8) 
        THEN 'NULL'
    END,
    G.grade,
    S.Marks
FROM Students S, Grades G;
```

Comment: What do I mean what do I mean @Strawberry?

Comment: @Strawberry They're trying to return 3 separate fields from each case statement. They either need 3 separate case statements, or as my answer provided, just pulling out `G.grade`, and `S.Marks`, as they don't appear to need to be in the case at all. (Updated my answer)

Comment: I think that's clearer - although I suspect that the OP should be radically reconsidering their whole approach to this problem!